# SetInterval, then clearInterval, then setInterval again

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a problem with my slider code.

Here I define a function to animate the slider based on how many elements there are (the more elements, the more times it should slide):

```
var animateSlider = function() {

        var howManyTimes = Math.ceil(newContainerWidth / parentWidth)-1;


        var repeatSlider = function() {
            howManyTimes = Math.ceil(newContainerWidth / parentWidth)-1;
            for (i=0;i<howManyTimes;i++) {
            // looped code
            $(".portfolio-slider").delay(2000).animate({
                        marginLeft: - (slideDistance * (i+1) )
                    }, 500);

            console.log(howManyTimes);
        }
        $(".portfolio-slider").delay(2000).animate({
                        marginLeft: 0
                    }, 500);
    }

    // and this is where I set the interval for sliding: 

    var intervalId;
    var intervalId = function() {
        setInterval(repeatSlider,howManyTimes * 500);
    }
    intervalId();

    // here's where I tried putting:
   // clearInterval(intervalId)
   // just to see if it clears it, but it didn't, the code interval just kept on replaying.

    }
```

Here I start the slider if autoplay is set to true:

```
    // fires the slider if autoplay option is set to true
    if (autoplay) {
    animateSlider();
        }
```

And here's what happens when I click on a button with ".filter" class - it filters the elements (code removed as it works and it's not what I want to focus on) and then initiates the animateSlider function so it can recalculate the number of elements and how many times it's supposed to slide:

```
        $('.filter').click(function(){
        // it does some stuff and then animates the slider again so it recalculates the widths and number of times it's supposed to slide:

        animateSlider();
    });
```

The problem is that I don't think it restarts the function, instead it fires it again and again and it doesn't recalculate how many times the slider should slide (so when I filter elements, it slides empty slides as well as those with elements).

I'm aware of the clearInterval() function, but I've tried putting it under the setInterval without success.

The ideal behavior should be - the slider slides, after a click on ".filter" the interval stops and restarts with new width and number of elements (instead of firing many times without stopping).

It's the second day that I'm trying to deal with this, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: never use interval, use setTimeout that calls to himself

Comment: If you want to use clearInterval you need to hold a ref to it, i.e. something like `var intervalTimer = setInterval(repeatSlider,howManyTimes * 500);` and then you can use `clearInterval(intervalTimer)` aftewards

Comment: But isn't it what I did here? 

        var intervalId = function() {
            setInterval(repeatSlider,howManyTimes * 500);
        }
       intervalId();

Later on I tried clearInterval(intervalId) and it didn't work, no errors in the console whatsoever.

Comment: you'll need to return the `setInterval` from your func if you want to do it that way, but the wrapping func is unnecessary

Comment: Will Jenkins, I don't exactly get what you mean by returning the setInterval from the function (I removed the function wrap though), could you please be more specific?

Comment: @oneday - what you're doing is assigning function to `intervalId`

Answer (score 0):

As Will Jenkins has said, you need to return setInterval() to get the reference of the interval function created. Your wrapper func actualy doesn't return anything. You could do this:

```
var intervalId = function() { 
    return setInterval(repeatSlider,howManyTimes * 500); 
}
```

or

```
var intervalId = setInterval(repeatSlider,howManyTimes * 500);
```

Comment: Ok, so for now I did this:

        var intervalId = function() { 
      return setInterval(repeatSlider,howManyTimes * 500); 
  }
  intervalId();
  clearInterval(intervalId);

Is that what you meant? The interval runs, but still doesn't clear.

Comment: Ok, I think return value of the intervalId() needs to be saved in another var: `var id = intervalId(); clearInterval(id);`